# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on object 'tableName', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, iis

I try to SELECT some data from SQL Server via my ASP.NET MVC web-app which is hosted in a Local IIS 7 and I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied
>   on object 'tableName', database 'dbName', schema 'dbo'.

Knowing that all the `IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated`'s privileges are checked, how do I to fix this, please?

Stack trace:

> [RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference]    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +200
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0) +924    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Header_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Users\Nectarys\desktop\monitoringn_web\monitoring2 -
>   copy\monitoringn\Views\Shared_Header.cshtml:11
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +158    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Nectarys\desktop\monitoringn_web\monitoring2 -
>   copy\monitoringn\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:13
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +89
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) +233
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +291
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +378    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +855148    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +839620
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +51
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Also, I've `grant SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE on dbo.tableName to "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated";`. I've did this by selecting the dbName and making in new script in which I've written that line.

Answer (score 3):

Your db user do not have rights to read from table's in db. You can give it db_owner rights and it should work.

1. Login to SQL server
2. Go to your database --> expand it
3. Security--> your db user
4. Right Click--> properties
5. Make sure that db_owner is selected

Comment: good thought making it dbowner narrow down to exact problem. of course later  one can set relevant required permission.

Comment: db_owner is an elevated privilege you shouldn't be using unless the user is responsible for creating or maintaining database schema. Use the db_datareader and db_datawriter database roles instead, that should be granted the necessary privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue.
I already had done changing permissions to 'db_owner', but it still didn't fix my problem.
Then I changed DefaultAppPool to 'NetworkService' in IIS Manager. It fixed my issue.